# Python crashes when dereferencing external ctypes pointers

Tags: python, windows, ctypes

I'm playing with `ctypes` and `ReadProcessMemory` in windows.

I would like to be able to read a chunk of memory and cast it into a ctypes type then access the correct values.

Currently this fails when dereferencing pointers. This is a minimal example:

```
# a minimal example
from ctypes import *
import win32api

class Test(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('p', POINTER(c_int)),
        ('pp', POINTER(POINTER(c_int)))
    ]

rpm = windll.kernel32.ReadProcessMemory
PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = 0x1F0FFF

pid = 10520
addr = 0x409E4260
process = win32api.OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, pid)

size = sizeof(Test)
buff = create_string_buffer(size)
bytes_read = c_size_t()

success = rpm(
    process.handle,
    addr,           # where to read from
    buff,    # output
    size,           # how much to read
    byref(bytes_read)
)

if not success:
    print " Error reading memory: " + str(get_last_error())
else:
    test = cast(buff, POINTER(Test)).contents
    print test
    # access pointers
    print test.p
    print test.pp
    # dereference pointers
    print test.p.contents
    print test.pp.contents
```

Those last two lines crash python, I assume because it's trying to access another process's memory. (?)

I've written a recursive function that can dereference pointers by repeatedly calling ReadProcessMemory, however this is clunky with complex structures.

**What am I doing wrong? What's the best way to do this?**

Comment: Dereferencing the pointer tries to access the address in your process address space. It crashes because there's nothing there; it's an unmapped address.

Comment: @eryksun Ahh! That makes sense. Is there a good way of overriding the default dereference operation so it looks in the external memory?

Comment: Did you every find out a solution to this? I'm have the same problem I think.

Comment: @adamb It was a while ago so cannot remember. I've just now looked at my code and appear to have set `.process` property to the external process after `cast`ing. In the example it would be `test.process = process`.